# Raw Type warning extending a Generic Class

Tags: java, generics

I'm confused by the scenario described below where I am extending a generic class.  The class I am extending is below:

```
public abstract class PresenterWidget<V extends View> extends HandlerContainerImpl
...
```

At first, I had this working (warning  free) using the child class below:

```
public abstract class SideBarPresenter<V extends SideBarPresenter.MyView> extends PresenterWidget<SideBarPresenter.MyView> {

    interface MyView extends View {
        void doSomething();
    }
...
```

But I want to convert `MyView` to an abstract class so I can implement a method.  The way I think it makes sense is below.

```
public abstract class SideBarPresenter<V extends SideBarPresenter.MyView> extends PresenterWidget<SideBarPresenter.MyView> {

    abstract class MyView implements View {
        void doSomething() {}
    }
...
```

The problem is this produces 2 warnings, both stating:

> SideBarPresenter.MyView is a raw type. References to generic type
>   SideBarPresenter.MyView should be parameterized

Should I just ignore this warning or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Never, **ever**, ignore any warnings. They are there for a good reason. For raw types, refer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it

Comment: @4castle View is an interface

Comment: @Tunaki thanks for the reply, I have actually worked with raw types quite a bit but I am struggling with this specific scenario.  I agree though on never ignoring warnings, that's why I am posting this question :)

Comment: View **is** a class ([Ref](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/View.html))

Comment: This is com.gwtplatform.mvp.client.View

Comment: Ah, then how did `extends View` work previously?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105462/discussion-between-the-gilbert-arenas-dagger-and-4castle).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should make MyView a `static` class. Otherwise its actually an inner class of a SideBarPresenter instance and that's probably where your generics warning is coming in. Inner interfaces are `static` by default.